# How to avoid bulk operation error while executing n1ql query, couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm executing n1ql query on couchbase. The query sometimes throws **"bulk get operation error"**. 
How to overcome this?

[image: How to avoid bulk get operation error in couchbase?]

Comment: what is the cluster topology like? single install? multiple nodes? looks like a connectivity issue / connection drop by the OS or something on the network...

Comment: only one cluster, with single node. sometimes, the query is working properly ( its giving output).. but, sometimes its throwing the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

post the query, EXPLAIN output, number of documents in the bucket, and result size your are expecting, couchbase version etc. Can you also check the error logs for any errors/warnings. https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-20318 seems to have fixed in 4.5.1.